# Error: aplay: main:831: audio open error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyttsx3, codespaces

I'm trying to run pyttsx3 on my codespace. But, it does not seem to be working
I keep gettiong this error
aplay: main:831: audio open error: No such file or directory

I tried running pyttsx3 file on the vs code in my windows pc and it works fine.

I already tried the solutions in stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What is your codespace? Is it a VM?

Comment: I think It's ubuntu.

Comment: It seems to be the problem of the package. You can open an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3).